# Converter tudo a horas ou tudo a minutos em mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela com o dois campos Inicio e Fim do `Tipo de dados Time`.
Exemplo de registos que tenho na tabela:

- 09:30:00 10:00:00
- 10:00:00 11:00:00
- 11:00:00 12:00:00

Como mostro, tenho horas inteiras e meias horas, como pode ter só 20 minutos ou 45 minutos por exemplo.

Agora pretendo fazer a diferença de horas e depois somar o total de horas por cliente.

O problema é que quando não tenho horas inteiras, por exemplo tenho 5 registos do mesmo cliente de 30 minutos, logo são 2:30 minutos, a consulta mostra o resultado como 1:50, porque está a somar 30 cinco vezes.

**Query:**

```
SELECT C.codigoutente,
       C.nome AS Utente,
       C.descricaovalencia AS Valência,
       REPLACE(CAST(SUM(SEC_TO_TIME(C.Minutos))/100 AS DECIMAL (15,2)), '.', ':') AS `Horas Consumidas`,
       CONVERT(CONCAT(CAST(SUM(C.Valor) AS DECIMAL (15,2)), '€'), char(8))  AS `Valor Total`

FROM 
(SELECT B.codigoutente,
        B.nome,
        B.descricaovalencia,
        B.`Data`,
        B.Minutos,
        IF(B.nome = 'CLASSE', (B.Minutos*10)/60, (B.Minutos*12)/60) AS Valor

FROM 
(SELECT A.codigoutente,
        A.nome,
        A.descricaovalencia,
        A.`Data`,
        A.`Horas Consumidas`,
        CAST(TIME_TO_SEC(A.`Horas Consumidas`)/60 AS DECIMAL(15,0)) AS Minutos       

FROM 
(SELECT centrodb.registoFisioterapia.id,
        centrodb.utentes.codigoutente,
        centrodb.utentes.nome,
        centrodb.utentes.descricaovalencia,
        centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data`,
        Inicio,
        Fim,
        centrodb.colaboradores.Nome AS Colaborador,
        TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')) AS `Horas Consumidas`

FROM centrodb.registoFisioterapia LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes

ON centrodb.utentes.Id = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.utente

LEFT OUTER JOIN colaboradores

ON centrodb.colaboradores.codigo = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.Nome) AS A) AS B

) AS C

GROUP BY C.codigoutente, C.nome, C.descricaovalencia
```

O resultado correto então devia ser 2:30 minutos e não 1:50 minutos. Alguém pode ajudar?

Alteração:

```
SELECT B.codigoutente,
       B.nome,
       B.descricaovalencia AS Valência,
       SUM(B.Minutos) AS `Horas Consumidas`,
       CONVERT(CONCAT(CAST(SUM(B.Valor) AS DECIMAL (15,2)), '€'), char(8))  AS `Valor Total`

FROM 
(SELECT A.codigoutente,
        A.nome,
        A.descricaovalencia,
        A.`Data`,
        A.`Minutos`,
        IF(A.nome = 'CLASSE', (A.`Minutos`*10), (A.`Minutos`*12)) AS Valor

FROM 
(SELECT centrodb.registoFisioterapia.id,
        centrodb.utentes.codigoutente,
        centrodb.utentes.nome,
        centrodb.utentes.descricaovalencia,
        centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data`,
        Inicio,
        Fim,
        centrodb.colaboradores.Nome AS Colaborador,
        CAST(TIME_TO_SEC(TiMEDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')))/60/60 AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS `Minutos`

FROM centrodb.registoFisioterapia LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes

ON centrodb.utentes.Id = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.utente

LEFT OUTER JOIN colaboradores

ON centrodb.colaboradores.codigo = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.Nome) AS A) AS B

GROUP BY B.codigoutente, B.nome, B.descricaovalencia
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Como fazer

Você pode usar o `TIME_TO_SEC`, assim ele converte sua hora em segundos, e você divide por 60 para minutos, e novamente por 60 para horas:

Exemplo:

```
SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT('22:30','%H:%i')) - TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT('10:00','%H:%i')))/60/60;

// ou

SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT('22:00','%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT('10:30','%H:%i')))/60/60;
```

Na sua query:

```
SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i')) - TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')))/60/60;

// ou

SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')))/60/60;
```

---

#### Complemento

Além disso, existem outras funções, as vezes possam ser úteis:

Diferença das horas:

```
Hour(TIMEDIFF(Fim,Inicio)) as Horas
```

Diferença dos minutos:

```
Minute(TIMEDIFF(Fim,Inicio)) as Minutos
```

Diferença dos segundos:

```
Second(TIMEDIFF(Fim,Inicio)) as Segundos
```

---

Link útil: [timestampdiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

---

### UPDATE 1

Como visto pelo CHAT, o seu Banco irá trazer as horas em quantidade(2,5) e não no formato de exibição (2:30).

Convertendo no `SELECT`:

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(A.Minutos)),'%i:%s') AS Minutos,
```

Convertendo no PHP:

Se nunca for passar de 24hs pode usar assim:

```
echo date('H:i', mktime(0,$minutos*60)); 
ou 
echo date('H:i', mktime(0,$horas));
```

Se poderá passar de 24hs, terá que fazer manualmente (existem várias formas):

```
function convertHoras($horas, $formato = '%02d:%02d') {

   $qHoras = floor($horas);
   $qMinutos = ($horas % 60);

   return sprintf($formato, $qHoras, $qMinutos);
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563535/convert-number-of-minutes-into-hours-minutes-using-php)

Comment: Ainda só falta uma coisa, agora em vez de aparecer 1:50, aparece 2:50, mas devia aparecer 2:30, podes ajudar?

Comment: Qual a hora inicio e fim ?

Comment: Coloquei a alteração que fiz na pergunta. Tenho Inicio 09:30 e Fim 10:00, como tenho inicio 10:00 e Fim 10:30, depende do horário

Comment: Sim, mas aí para dar um total somando mais de um registro, seria outro caso, usando o `GROUP BY` e fazendo um `SUM` no campo de horas. Por exemplo, execute essa query, veja que está trazendo valor em horas corretamente: `SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT('10:00','%H:%i')) - TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT('09:30','%H:%i')))/60/60;`

Comment: Coloque no http://sqlfiddle.com/, que eu faço o GROUP BY, se ele não estiver funcionando, pois ao meu ver, está

Comment: Você joga o script de criação e inserção dos dados do lado, clica em "Build Schema"... dando ok, copie o link e manda aqui...

Comment: Acho que seu problema está no SUM, porque ele deve estar somando errado... ao invés de converter para horas (/60/60) por registro, converta no SUM... SUM(tempo)/60/60, assim ele irá somar tudo em segundos, e fazer a divisão só depois no total, no select final, entendeu ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75239/discussion-between-rbz-and-iniciante).